# Infinite Loops in 2 Functions/Methods inside an Object

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, methods, infinite-loop

I am trying to output (a) result(s) based on an infinite number of loops in my team object below. I know that the code worked before I automated `calcAvg` method with a for-loop. Now that I've included a for-loop here, I am not able to return a value back, and therefore, nothing comes out of `checkWinner` method.

Could someone please help?

```js
const team = {
    koalas: {
        round1: [65, 54, 49],
        round2: [23, 34, 27]
    },
    dolphins: {
        round1: [64, 23, 71],
        round2: [85, 54, 41]
    },

    calcAvg: function () {
        let d;
        let k;
        for (let i = 1; i < (this.koalas["round" + i] && this.dolphins["round" + i]); i++) {
            k = this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] = this.koalas["round" + i].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.koalas["round" + i].length;
            d = this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] = this.dolphins["round" + i].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.dolphins["round" + i].length;

            console.log(d, k);
        }
        return [d, k];
    },

    checkWinner: function () {
        for (let i = 1; i < (this.koalas["round" + i].length && i < this.dolphins["round" + i].length); i++) {
            if (this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] >= this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] * 2) {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: Koalas win!`);
            } else if (this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] >= this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] * 2) {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: Dolphins win!`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: No one wins, as at least one team needs to score double the score of the other team to win`);
            }
        }
    }
}

team.calcAvg();
team.checkWinner();
```

Comment: You need to split your condition—`foo <= x && y` isn’t correct, `foo <= x && foo <= y` is (at least logically; I’m not addressing the content of the expressions).

Comment: This is not working for me. Please reply with a full code.

Comment: “This is not working for me” is non-diagnostic; there’s no way of knowing what you actually did. I’d recommend doing some debugging by logging or stepping, perhaps setting some breakpoints and checking assumptions made in the code.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'd, however, appreciate the exact spots that aren't working in my code to understand where I am wrong, as I am learning this at the moment.

Comment: Can you please debug your code in a debugger, and step through the code? It will help resolve several things yourself. Also, please provide a runnable snippet in your question (without Vue -- which is really unrelated) - you can use the toolbar in the editor to insert a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in this line:

```
for (let i = 1; i < (this.koalas["round" + i] && this.dolphins["round" + i]); i++) {
```

- The `i < (` should be removed (and the closing `)`). This is because `i` should not be compared with another number, but the condition should check that the `"round" + i` *exists* (is defined).

So:

```
for (let i = 1; this.koalas["round" + i] && this.dolphins["round" + i]; i++) {
```

You have the same issue in the other function.

```js
const team = {
    koalas: {
        round1: [65, 54, 49],
        round2: [23, 34, 27]
    },
    dolphins: {
        round1: [64, 23, 71],
        round2: [85, 54, 41]
    },

    calcAvg: function () {
        let d;
        let k;
        for (let i = 1; this.koalas["round" + i] && this.dolphins["round" + i]; i++) {
            k = this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] = this.koalas["round" + i].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.koalas["round" + i].length;
            d = this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] = this.dolphins["round" + i].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.dolphins["round" + i].length;

            console.log(d, k);
        }
        return [d, k];
    },

    checkWinner: function () {
        for (let i = 1; this.koalas["round" + i] && this.dolphins["round" + i]; i++) {
            if (this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] >= this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] * 2) {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: Koalas win!`);
            } else if (this.dolphins["AvgRound" + i] >= this.koalas["AvgRound" + i] * 2) {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: Dolphins win!`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Round: ${i}: No one wins, as at least one team needs to score double the score of the other team to win`);
            }
        }
    }
}

team.calcAvg();
team.checkWinner();
```

A more general remark on your code: it is an antipattern to define object properties that have an sequential number in their name. In that case you should just define an array instead of a plain object.

Secondly, since you relate koala info with dolphin info *per round*, you should really combine those data in one object *per round*.
So in your case you should better organise your data like this:

```
rounds: [
    [
        {koalas: 65, dolphins: 64}, 
        {koalas: 54, dolphins: 23}, 
        {koalas: 49, dolphins: 71}
    ], [
        {koalas: 23, dolphins: 85},
        {koalas: 34, dolphins: 54},
        {koalas: 27, dolphins: 41}
    ]
]
```

Obviously that will mean a lot of changes in your code.

Comment: This code is not working for me either. There's no errors shown or any output given in the console. Can you please look into it again?

Comment: Did you correct the same issue in the second function?

Comment: If you provide a runnable snippet in your question, I can copy it and make sure it runs correctly in my answer.

Comment: the code that i pasted in my question is exactly the way it appears in my IDE...

Comment: sorry, im a little confused what you mean by that?

Comment: Stack Snippets. In the question editor there is a toolbar. One of the tools embeds a runnable snippet into your question, in which you can type the code. Then we can run it. It should not include Vue code.

Comment: done, thanks! please lmk what i still did wrong here

Comment: I updated my answer. Snippet also added, so it runs without errors now, and it outputs some results.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I've been looking for. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with `rounds` object, btw! I spent a couple of hours on it, but it finally worked, and I like your proposed solution better now :)

Comment: Thanks for giving that feedback! ;-)